# How to browse directory server machine instead of local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-applications, directory-browsing

**Scenario:**

1.My web application is hosted in the following IP (13.67.3.12).

2.We have 'Browse' option for selecting the file. If I open the browser window from the client machine (13.67.3.21) it is showing local machine directory instead of it should open server (13.67.3.12) machine folder directory. Is it possible in web application?
Is there any way to do it using javascript/jquery/node.js/anytools?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a shared folder on the server, then assign permissions to the share based on either a active directory service account, or user group. In the file dialog options, you can set the start directory of the dialog. You can set this to default to the shared folder location.

Comment: In this way I can access only the server shared folders alone. Is there any possibility to access the whole machine directory structure as like local machine.